# how should the webgame client select servers In ActionScript3?

Tags: actionscript-3

If the game has more servers ?
there is No login server now , so i don't know how to access specific server when user login.
i think that should decide before the socket connects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommend  the flashvars , 
you can accept the server id from platform and the back-end will create .html file to response the user . 
the .html file includes game.swf and flashvars  (server id ),so that's is !